# How to know if 'ms-CommandBar' component has been loaded using SPFX extensions

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, spfx-extensions

[image]

I would like to hide the above commandbar in all pages using javascript in spfx extensions(application customizer).

I have tried the below code

```
@override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then(_ => {
      pnp.setup({
        spfxContext: this.context
      });
    }).then(()=>{
      $(document).ready(()=>{
        pnp.sp.web.currentUser.get().then(d=>{
          pnp.sp.web.associatedOwnerGroup.users.getById(d.Id)
          .get().then((data)=>{
            console.log("Site Owner");
          }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log("Not Site Owner");            
            //hidding the button divs on banner for current users who are not owner
            $(".commandBarWrapper").bind("load",()=>{
              if($('.ms-CommandBar')){
                $(".ms-CommandBar").hide();                
              }           
          });
        });          
    });
  });
}
```

Is there any other way to know if the component has been loaded?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the hide logic by injecting a custom CSS so you don't need care about the page element load time.

```
 public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);
    const cssUrl: string = this.properties.cssurl;
    if (cssUrl) {
        // inject the style sheet
        const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
        let customStyle: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
        customStyle.href = cssUrl;
        customStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
        customStyle.type = "text/css";
        head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", customStyle);
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
```

Check [this demo](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/).